# Timefold: Is it possible to filter out all trivial 2opt moves for PlanningListVariable?

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

I'm trying to solve tsp with **PlanningListVariable**.

I've configured **kOptMoves** like this:

```
  <kOptListMoveSelector>
    <minimumK>2</minimumK>
    <maximumK>2</maximumK>
  </kOptListMoveSelector>
```

And I see in the log trivial moves with **abs(firstEndpointIndex - secondEndpointIndex) <= 1**.

For example:

```
2023-12-07 14:03:20,831 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (pool-7-thread-1)     LS step (91293), time spent (60096), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/192), picked move (2-Opt(firstEntity=salesman.mainModel.domain.Route@5ad597bf, secondEntity=salesman.mainModel.domain.Route@5ad597bf, firstEndpointIndex=99, secondEndpointIndex=99)).
2023-12-07 14:03:20,831 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (pool-7-thread-1)     LS step (91294), time spent (60096), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/51), picked move (2-Opt(firstEntity=salesman.mainModel.domain.Route@5ad597bf, secondEntity=salesman.mainModel.domain.Route@5ad597bf, firstEndpointIndex=8, secondEndpointIndex=7)).
2023-12-07 14:03:20,831 DEBUG [ai.tim.sol.cor.imp.loc.DefaultLocalSearchPhase] (pool-7-thread-1)     LS step (91295), time spent (60096), score (0hard/-20852279soft),     best score (0hard/-20852279soft), accepted/selected move count (1/92), picked move (2-Opt(firstEntity=salesman.mainModel.domain.Route@5ad597bf, secondEntity=salesman.mainModel.domain.Route@5ad597bf, firstEndpointIndex=96, secondEndpointIndex=95)).
```

I am quite sure these moves are trivial, so I want to filter them.

I know the common way to do that is to use filter-class with **SelectionFilter** interface. But the problem is **KOptListMove** class is not public, so I can't use it in my filter class. Is there another way?

Comment: A note: `firstEndpointIndex=8, secondEndpointIndex=7` is not trivial, If your list has 10 elements, it flips the path [8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6] to [6,5,4,3,2,1,0,9,8]. That is, if `firstEndpointIndex > secondEndpointIndex`, it wraps around back to the start of the list.  That said, `firstEndpointIndex=99, secondEndpointIndex=99` and `firstEndpointIndex=99, secondEndpointIndex=100` would both be trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a good point. We probably should've made the class public. What bothers me more though is that you even have to write a filter like this; these trivial situations should have been filtered out by default. Something to fix for the next version of [Timefold Solver](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver).

At this time, I cannot think of a workaround.